# Logic errors with password authentication code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let pass = password.text
        var firpass = ""
        var bool = false;
        ref.child(name.text as! String).child("password").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { dataSnapshot in
          firpass = dataSnapshot.value as? String ?? ""
            if firpass == pass {
                bool = true
            }
            if bool {
                self.sendname = self.name.text!
                let vc = DatabaseTableViewController(nibName: "DatabaseTableViewController", bundle: nil)
                vc.finalName = self.sendname
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "username", sender: self)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Incorrect username or password", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "failed", sender: self)
            }
        })
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String?, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let ident = identifier {
            if ident == "failed" {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

When I give the right username and password, I go to the next page, but I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<OCRApp.ViewController: 0x105e00f60>) has no segue with identifier 'failed''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1877aaa48 0x1874d1fa4 0x18b206010 0x104a5b58c 0x104a5ba20 0x104aaa19c 0x104aaa598 0x104a8bb40 0x105cd97fc 0x105cdabd8 0x105ce8c34 0x1877285e4 0x1877235d8 0x187722adc 0x1916a8328 0x18b81dae0 0x104a6cdb0 0x1875ac360)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

When I give the wrong username/password, I still went to the next page, and I got the above error but with identifier `failed` instead; when I took out the line `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "failed", sender: self)`, I still went to the next page and got the message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x102978a00>  on <OCRApp.ViewController: 0x10170a650> which is already presenting <OCRApp.DatabaseTableViewController: 0x10206beb0>
```

What I want is to progress to the next page without errors if you put the correct authentication, and to get just the alert and stay on current page if you give incorrect authentication. How do I do this?

Comment: Refer this tutorial will help for segue concept https://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/

Comment: why you perform segue you are already pushing view controller, you can not perform both at same time. From you code, i think you doesn't require that segue code.

Answer (score 2):

Either use push or performSegue, you cant use both at same time. that will push your view controller twice. I have updated the code below.

```
@IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let pass = password.text
    var firpass = ""
    var bool = false;
    ref.child(name.text as! String).child("password").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { dataSnapshot in
        firpass = dataSnapshot.value as? String ?? ""
        if firpass == pass {
            bool = true
        }
        if bool {
            self.sendname = self.name.text!
            let vc = DatabaseTableViewController(nibName: "DatabaseTableViewController", bundle: nil)
            vc.finalName = self.sendname
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) // either use push or performSegue, you cant use both.
            //   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "username", sender: self)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Incorrect username or password", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) // if there is an error, you do not need to performSegue.
            //    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "failed", sender: self)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not have information about your segues, I suggest you `instantiate` your next ViewController. You can use something like this:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as? NextViewController
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```